# Reset Dropdown after removing items

Tags: jquery

I use the detach-method to remove multiple items from a dropdown when clicking a button. I also have a reset button - but I can't figure how to reset my dropdown.

```
$("#presets option[value='" + id + "']").detach();
```

Comment: by reset you mean you want to clear all dropdown items or select a default value in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restore the items that have been removed, and preservation of order is not important, the solution is simple:

```
var removed = [];
// your buttons to remove single items
$('#remove1').on('click', function () {
    removed.push($('#presets option[value="1"]').detach());
});
$('#remove2').on('click', function () {
    removed.push($('#presets option[value="2"]').detach());
});
// button to restore items
$('#restore').on('click', function () {
    removed.forEach(function ($e) {
        $('#presets').append($e);
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4te56/)**

---

If preservation of order is important, then the you need to sort the elements before restoring:

```
var removed = $();
$('#remove1').on('click', function () {
    removed = removed.add($('#presets option[value="1"]').detach());
});
$('#remove2').on('click', function () {
    removed = removed.add($('#presets option[value="2"]').detach());
});
$('#restore').on('click', function () {
    var $opts = removed.add('#presets option');
    removed = $();
    $opts.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseInt($(a).attr('value')) > parseInt($(b).attr('value'));
    });
    $('#presets').html($opts);
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4te56/1/)**

Comment: Thats smart - but somehow the restore doesn't work with my dropdown:  `<div class="dropdown" id="presets">
    <%= f.label :render_preset_id, "Render Preset" %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:render_preset_id, @render_presets, :id, :name, :selected => RenderPreset.find(WhatsCurrent.find(1).render_preset).id)   %>
  </div>`